# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 How to parse content Text in suitescript

Tags: netsuite, content-type, suitescript

i am trying to update a vendor record status field using suitescript 2.0,passing the body in postman tool and is working fine for content JSON but the problem is when i try content as Text its getting error don't know how to read body value in suitescript 2.0.

[input body from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ybI.jpg)

### sample code is

```
function doPut(context) 
{
var obj=JSON.stringify(context.ids);-----here is the error context is empty
// tried JSON.parse also getting undefined
log.debug('str: '+obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide the exact error message that would be helpful.

But in the mean time a few things that you should verify in your script, if you do not pass **application/JSON** in header, and your data is object, you need to explicitly parse it into JSON(i.e use `JSON.parse()` on the request-body), and your response type too should be in the same format i.e your response type should match content-type in the request.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may have the wrong Content-type. Should be Application-json. If not try Json.parse on the body if you're using text/plain. First step is to always log the context to console or run Object.keys(context) to see what's there. Also make sure doPut is exported as a function